# Return multiple values for 'Then' clause in an SQL case expression

Tags: mysql, sql

My "files" table data is

```
fileid   file1      file2
  1      abc.pdf    abcde.pdf
  2      ghf.pdf    ghfjkl.pdf
  3      hjy.pdf    hjyui.pdf
```

my "sampletable" data is

```
 fileid       names
   1           abc
   2           ghf
   3           hjy
   4           juk
```

I need output like

```
   fileid      names    files

     1          abc      abc.pdf
     1          abc      abcde.pdf
     2          ghf      ghf.pdf
     2          ghf      ghfjkl.pdf
     3          hjy      hjy.pdf
     3          hjy      hjyui.pdf
```

i tried the following query but not getting desired output

```
 select st.fileid,st.contolnames,
 case when st.fileid in (select fileid from Files) 
 then f.file1 
 when st.fileid in (select fileid from Files)  then f.file2 end as Files
 from sampletable st
 join Files f on f.fileid=st.fileid
```

Please help with this
demo: 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=08337e2ee351b573bc902f06fcfba272

Comment: why using case? just use the join and the columns!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - use `UNION`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9162ccf79a9d4b9b8cc1bd9a9ee41b2d)**

```
    select * from
    (
    select a.fileid,contolnames,file1 as files
    from Files a inner join sampletable b on a.fileid=b.fileid
    union
    select a.fileid,contolnames,file2 as files 
    from Files a inner join sampletable b on  a.fileid=b.fileid
  )A order by fileid
```

OUTPUT:

```
fileid  contolnames files
1         abc   abc.pdf
1         abc   abcdef.pdf
2         ghf   ghf.pdf
2         ghf   ghfjkl.pdf
3         hjy   hjyui.pdf
3         hjy   hjy.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate two rows for each record you can use `CROSS JOIN` like following query to get the desired output.

```
select f.fileid, 
       st.contolnames as names, 
       case 
         when t.x = 1 then f.file1 
         else file2 
       end            as files 
from   Files f 
       inner join sampletable st 
               on st.fileid = f.fileid 
       cross join (select 1 x 
                   union 
                   select 2 x) t(x) 
order  by fileid
```

[**Online Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d5857149cc7ea618f3ddb7dde9c0a3d3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. it's working for me..

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1(fileid INT IDENTITY, file1 varchar(50), file2 varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE #Temp2(fileid INT IDENTITY, name varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE  #Temp3(fieldid int, name varchar(50), file1 varchar(50) , file2 varchar(50))
create table #Temp4 (fieldid int, name varchar(50), files varchar(50))  

INSERT INTO #Temp1 VALUES( 'abc.pdf','abcde.pdf')
INSERT INTO #Temp1 VALUES( 'ghf.pdf','ghfjkl.pdf')
INSERT INTO #Temp1 VALUES( 'hjy.pdf','hjyui.pdf')


INSERT INTO #Temp2 VALUES( 'abc')
INSERT INTO #Temp2 VALUES( 'ghf')
INSERT INTO #Temp2 VALUES( 'hjy')
INSERT INTO #Temp2 VALUES( 'juk')

SELECT * FROM #Temp1
SELECT * FROM #Temp2


INSERT INTO #Temp3
SELECT * FROM (SELECT B.fileid ,name , 
CASE WHEN Name Like SUBSTRING(A.file1,1,3) THEN file1  END AS files, 
CASE WHEN Name Like SUBSTRING(A.file2,1,3) THEN  file2 END AS files1   
FROM #Temp1 A , #Temp2 B ) AA WHERE files IS NOT NULL

INSERT INTO #Temp4 SELECT fieldid,name,file1 FROM  #Temp3 

INSERT INTO #Temp4 SELECT fieldid,name,file2 FROM  #Temp3 

SELECT * FROM #Temp4 ORDER BY name asc

DROP TABLE #Temp1
DROP TABLE #Temp2
DROP TABLE #Temp3
DROP TABLE #Temp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a join with the UNPIVOT of the first Table.

```
select f.fileid, name, files 
from Files f 
unpivot (files for name in (file1,file2)) 
join sampletable s on f.fileid = s.fileid
```